# My RecyclerView ContextMenu doesn't show

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contextmenu

Where did I get this wrong?
My Context Menu doesn't show, I already moved the `setOnCreateContextMenuListener` and `OnCreateContextMenu` Inside my `ViewHolder` and still doesn't show.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {
    ImageView imageview;
    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_imageName);
        itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        String id = fArray.get(info.position).substring(fArray.get(info.position).lastIndexOf("/")+1).replace(".jpg", "");
        if (v.getId()==R.id.gridView1) {
            menu.setHeaderTitle(id);
            EditName = id;
            String[] menuItems = {"Edit"};

            for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
                menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener, MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener {
      ImageView imageview;
      TextView textView;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_imageName);
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            MenuItem star=menu.add(Menu.NONE,1,1,"Star");
            MenuItem edit=menu.add(Menu.NONE,2,2,"Edit");
            MenuItem delete=menu.add(Menu.NONE,3,3,"Delete");
            star.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            edit.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            int s1=list.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId();
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "pressed on star", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "pressed on edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "pressed on edit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank You, 

itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this); < This part is my problem.
I used getActivity()

Comment: If its fine then tick the answer.

Comment: Follow up mate, 
Do You know how to get the Clicked item position in RecyclerView, it's a bit different with gridView mine doesn't work.

Comment: In BindViewholder you get the position

Comment: Yea saw it too, but how to properly pass it to class ViewHolder, I tried to add Global Variable 'position', and pass the value of 'BlindViewHolder' position in it, then I return new ViewHolder(v, position); at OnCreate,  But the result == Higher than one of current item selected, then suddenly will become random after few scrolls, (Sorry out of Question already can't create a new thread)

Comment: try getAdapterPosition() in VIewHolder